# Get list of all the updated values in Room database

Tags: android, android-room

Is there a way in the Room database to retrieve a list of data that has been updated?

Example: Suppose, I have a table called Note and I have an update query which is something like this:

```
@Query("UPDATE note SET archive = 1 WHERE date > '20200101'")
abstract suspend fun updateNote()
```

How can I get the list of notes which were updated?

I did some research, but couldn't find any reliable link or article. Any help appreciated. Cheers!

**EDIT:**

I think I can use distinctUntilChanged, but not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `@Transaction` method can solve your problem, like:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM note WHERE date > '20200101'")
suspend fun getFilteredNotes(): List<Note>

@Query("UPDATE note SET archive = 1 WHERE date > '20200101'")
suspend fun updateNote()

@Transaction
suspend fun getNotesAndUpdate(): List<Note> {
    val filteredNotes = getFilteredNotes()
    updateNote()
    return filteredNotes
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. I think I gave the wrong example, it's a bit complicated than that. I will update my question soon. But your solution did give me an idea! I'll upvote for that. Cheers!